# Github - how do I download the executable?

Tags: github, compilation, repository, executable, release

how does one download the compiled file from a github project.

For example I was trying to download sandboxie and was taken here where I managed to download the zip, but there is no exe in the zip:

> https://github.com/sandboxie/sandboxie ***(1)***

I then searched for the installation package via google and through https://m.majorgeeks.com/files/details/sandboxie.html managed to download the compiled exe. Checking the link location for the exe, it points to here:

> https://github-releases.githubusercontent.com/254327261/440a6e00-7d97-11eb-9289-9e5f62cb44fe?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20210323%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210323T060753Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=c3092c5eac115a0cb9ccfe5beafc58d8fdac12288c19adba380de01dc58e95b2&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=81162979&key_id=0&repo_id=254327261&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3DSandboxie-Classic-x64-v5.49.0.exe&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream
> ***(2)***

How would I get from ***(1)*** to ***(2)*** without having to google for the compiled file. Is there a location I have to go in github or do I have run some commands? I am also not a familiar with compiling exe's from the source files.

Comment: I have been to Github about a million times in order to download certain open source tools which in themselves I approve of very much. I have NEVER been able to find the actual executable without going back and forth between the several buttons and links on the Github page about a dozen times, every time ending up at some source code folder or the like which I agree to be very important for the contributors and programmers. WHY IS IT IMPOSSIBLE TO SIMPLY FIND AND DOWNLOAD THE FORKING EXECUTABLE ON ANY GITHUB PAGE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can't  `get from (1) to (2)`  because they are not same repository.

This is the repository the second link came from [repository](https://github.com/sandboxie-plus/Sandboxie)  if you go to Releases section [releases](https://github.com/sandboxie-plus/Sandboxie/releases) you will find the downloading link in the assets.

To make sure that this is the same repository  in the second link you will find `repo_id=254327261` and it is the same id of the repo I gave you the link above

Comment: That's it, and seems to be universal for now. Thank you @seif.